# Specific column import form text file

Tags: excel, matlab, text, multiple-columns, plaintext

I have many test files. I want to import only one column from each test file, and write it to an an Excel file. How do I do this?

For example, text file 1 (1).text and (2).text file.

```
file 1(1).txt column A,B,C,D
file 1(2).txt column A1,B1,C1,D1
```

I would like to get

```
A.exls == B B1
```

Comment: Take a look at ` textscan`  or ` dlmread`,  and of course ` xlsread`  and `xlswrite` . Please try a few things, and if you still need help, please update your question with what you've tried, then we can help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Vinit. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.